# How to add credentials to S3AsyncClient when uploading

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is AWS Java code example for async upload to S3:

```
S3AsyncClient client = S3AsyncClient.create();
CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = client.putObject(
PutObjectRequest.builder()
.bucket(BUCKET)
.key(KEY)
.build(),
AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(Paths.get("myfile.in"))
);
future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
try {
if (resp != null) {
System.out.println("my response: " + resp);
} else {
// Handle error
err.printStackTrace();
}
} finally {
// Lets the application shut down. Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
client.close();
}
});
```

I got it to work for a while, but just curious why are you allowed to upload to a bucket (that has blocked all public access turned on) without credentials?

Then for some reason my access key was deleted and I had to regenerated a new one, but now I am getting

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The AWS Access
>   Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: S3,
>   Status Code: 403, Request ID: 2FC0CEEB338D50CB)

. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
        AwsCredentialsProvider creds = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("my_access_key", "my_secret_key"));
        S3AsyncClient s3Client;
        try {
            s3Client = S3AsyncClient.builder().credentialsProvider(creds)
                    .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
                    .endpointOverride(new URI("https://abc.xyz.com:9021"))
                    .build();
            CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> futureGet = s3Client.putObject(
                    PutObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket("my_bucket_name")
                            .key("/somepath/anotherpath/myData.pdf")
                            .build(),
                            AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(Paths.get("myfile.in")));
            futureGet.get();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```